# Mesh not moving along with the rig/armature

Tags: mesh, rigging

I have made a rig and made it parent to my mesh. But the mesh still won't move along.

Background info:

1. The model was created in Nomad Sculpt and imported to Blender in obj. format.
2. I have checked that the weights are 1 and also performed "all transform" to the mesh.
3. Many parts but I have also joined them by pressing "ctrl+J".

I am so new to Blender and don't have much clue on it.

Greatly appreciate if anyone could help!!

File here for download:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14FohqPCM2WCE4lMY6DJ8lgJm1T-MHmb4/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your mesh has 3.7 million vertices! It's impossible to rig such a high-poly object (you don't even need so many vertices for sculpting):

[image]

you need to create a low-poly version of your object, it's called retopology, or restart from scratch (take some screenshots of your current character and use them as references). Look how 3D character wireframes look like, they have only several thousands vertices:

[image]

Comment: Oh god, thank you thank you. Now I know how my object should look like! I bet I would need to start again haha. Thank you so much!